# Shortcut for Render LaTeX Equation in Inkscape?

Tags: shortcut-keys, latex, inkscape

I need to use the LaTeX equation extension in Inkscape (`Extensions -> Render -> Mathematics -> LaTeX (pdflatex)`) (In Inkscape 1.2, it is `Extensions -> Render -> Formula (pdflatex)`).

It is quite painful to click through the menu items so many times to open it. I want to add a keyboard shortcut which would bring up the Extension window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Open `~/.config/inkscape/keys/default.xml` (create it if it does not exist), and add the following contents

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<keys name="My Customization">
    <bind key="k" modifiers="Ctrl,Alt"
          action="org.inkscape.generate.pdf_latex" display="true"/>
</keys>
```

Works in Inkscape 1.1.1 in Ubuntu 21.10. Now, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> to open the LaTeX dialog box.

---

This part of the answer works in *older versions* of Inkscape.

You should find or create file "`default.xml`" in your `<Inkscape-installation>` path or in user directory (for Ubuntu it's `~/.config/inkscape/keys` since v0.48) and add this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<keys name="My Customization">
    <bind key="k" modifiers="Ctrl,Alt"
          action="org.inkscape.effect.eqtexsvg" display="true"/>
</keys>
```

I've written about it [there](http://primary-matter.blogspot.com/2013/02/inkscape-adding-shortcut-for-render.html).

Comment: The link says "Permission denied"